# What is the reading of 0件？ れいけん or ゼロ件？Thanks!

Tags: kanji, readings

What is the reading of 0件？ れいけん or ゼロ件？Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reading is generally ゼロ件. I found an interesting article about the difference between ゼロ and れい. https://chigai-allguide.com/zero%EF%BC%88%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8%E9%9B%B6%EF%BC%88%E3%82%8C%E3%81%84%EF%BC%89/

Answer (score 4):

I think they would say ゼロ件,
れい is used more for other meanings
for instance if you reading a math book with many problems 
the sample problem with the solution will be called as **Mondai Rei**.  x+1=0 => x=-1.
(Mondai = problem, rei = 0)

Comment: Would this apply to 個, too, 0個 being ゼロこ rather than れいこ?